# Windows 8.1 primary language problems

Tags: windows-8, language

I recently bought a computer with Windows 8.1 installed.

It has both Hebrew and English and has English set as the system language.

Problem is that some of the menus appear in Hebrew.
This seems to be true only for menus in the "Start" screen but not for anything in the "old" format desktop.

For example, when I go via the "new" start-screen to the list of programs installed and then right-click one of them then the pop-up menu is in Hebrew rather than in English.

The original language of the OS was Hebrew with English added as an extra language-pack and then set as the system language.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem! Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Hi, I've found the solution. Please take a look here: http://superuser.com/a/827690/130526