# Cannot change Windows 8.1 to be entirely in English

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, language

I got my Dell laptop with a Hebrew Windows 8.1, and changed the display language to English using the language settings. Now most of the UI is in English, but some elements are still in Hebrew, even after I restarted.

Here is an example: for some reason the "Disk Capacity" menu appears in Hebrew!

[image]

How can I make windows be entirely in English with no traces of Hebrew?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed after installing *one* of these Windows updates:

[image]

I cannot tell which one has fixed the problem since they were all installed together.

Comment: Which ones specifically?

Comment: I don't know. All of them were installed at the same time. I cannot know which is the one responsible for the fix. Sorry

Comment: Your current answer indicates ALL (implied) of these updates are required which isn't really true since you don't know which updates are required.

Comment: I will correct this.